# How do I sort a go slice by multiple values?

Tags: sorting, go, slice

```
type Item struct {
    Y    int
    X    int
    otherProp    int
}
```

I have a slice of structs like the above one. How do I sort the slice `item []Item` by the X value first and then by the Y value like in SQLs `ORDER BY X,Y`?

I see that you can use `sort.Slice()` since go 1.8 but is there a simple way to solve this without looping over the slice several times?

Comment: You compare the X then the Y values. Can you show an example of where you're having trouble doing this? (`sort.Slice` isn't required, you could always do this with the standard `sort.Sort` too.)

Comment: The package even contains an example of how to do it in the general case: https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example__sortMultiKeys. Alternatively you can sort twice: First on Y and then stable (!) on X.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Following the first example from here: [Package sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/), I wrote the following...

Inside the `Less()` function I check if `X` are equal and if so, I then check `Y`.

[playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/1EzOiaw_UJ)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Item struct {
    X    int
    Y    int
    otherProp    int
}

func (i Item) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("X: %d, Y: %d, otherProp: %d\n", i.X, i.Y, i.otherProp)
}

// ByX implements sort.Interface for []Item based on
// the X field.
type ByX []Item

func (o ByX) Len() int           { return len(o) }
func (o ByX) Swap(i, j int)      { o[i], o[j] = o[j], o[i] }
func (o ByX) Less(i, j int) bool { 
    if o[i].X == o[j].X {
        return o[i].Y < o[j].Y
    } else {
        return o[i].X < o[j].X
    }
}

func main() {
    items := []Item{
        {1,2,3},
        {5,2,3},
        {3,2,3},
        {9,2,3},
        {1,1,3},
        {1,0,3},
    }

    fmt.Println(items)
    sort.Sort(ByX(items))
    fmt.Println(items)

}
```

output:

```
[X: 1, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 5, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 3, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 9, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 1, Y: 1, otherProp: 3
 X: 1, Y: 0, otherProp: 3
]
[X: 1, Y: 0, otherProp: 3
 X: 1, Y: 1, otherProp: 3
 X: 1, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 3, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 5, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
 X: 9, Y: 2, otherProp: 3
]
```

Answer (score 1):

> [...] is there a simple way to solve this without looping over the slice several times?

No. Comparison-based sorting basically always involves looping over the slice at least once plus a bit more. But do not worry: sort.Slice does not do too much work.

What's your question?